# Is there an HTML Canvas Video Context Buffer

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, video

The HTML audio context has a freely accessible source buffer that can be used to write bytes data directly to be played by the speakers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createBufferSource

Is there an equivalent 'image buffer source' that we can access and directly write/copy RGB data bytes?

**What I've tried**:

I implemented this pixel-by-pixel in the end using:

```
context.fillStyle = "rgb(" + source[pointer].toString() + "," + source[pointer+1].toString() + "," + source[pointer+2].toString() + ")";
```

and then doing a:

```
context.fillRect (x, y, 1, 1);
```

to draw this pixel by pixel to the canvas, which works out fine though I suspect that's not the most efficient way to go about doing it.

I am still open to other suggestions.

Comment: [`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) and [`putImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData) allow you to get/write an [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) object, which contains a `Uint8ClampedArray` of the RGBA values

Comment: My source image happens to be in a PPM format already which, after chopping off the header, is already a linearly stated R,G,B byte values for the entire image... is there a way to "feed" this directly somewhere into a buffer, without converting byte-by-byte into ImageData and then feeding the ImageData to the canvas? Thanks

Comment: You ask about image buffer source in the body of the question, but your title says "video". While video is certainly made up of images, the way they are generated and streamed are quite different, AFAIK.

Comment: the ImageData constructor accepts an Uint8ClampedArray as input, no need to feed each pixel one by one, but you need to specify the width and height of the image

Comment: Thanks Kaiido! Getting close now... I checked the ImageData constructor which accepts r,g,b,a (4 values) for each pixel... Are there any options for it to accept a plain rgb array (3 values) without the 'a' component? Thanks

Comment: @HereticMonkey Video is a bit of an ambiguous term. It can just mean a static image (as in video RAM, Video Graphic Array (VGA), video card, etc. ) or it can mean a series of frames to represent movement. I think the OP means the former.

Comment: @LeeTaylor The terms are quite well defined in HTML; there's the `img` element (and `Image` interface) for  displaying the former (and possibly animated versions of GIF and PNG in a pinch), and the `video` tag (and the `HTMLMediaElement` interface) for the latter. [MDN has an article on working with video (in the HTML meaning) on canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Manipulating_video_using_canvas).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm talking in the larger context of computing. Hence the terms sometimes get confused.

Comment: @James You cannot have RGB, only RGBA as imageData in HTML5. Just use a **FOR** loop to read the input pixels into your imageData object. For every 3 pixels that you read, you also write a 4th `alpha` value into imageData. If you update your question with what you've tried then we might advise or fix the code

Comment: @VC.One thank you, i implemented this pixel-by-pixel in the end using: context.fillStyle = "rgb(" + source[pointer].toString() + "," + source[pointer+1].toString() + "," + source[pointer+2].toString() + ")"; and then context.fillRect (x, y, 1, 1); to draw this pixel by pixel to the canvas, which works out fine though i suspect that's not the most efficient way to go about doing it... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, html5 canvas's [image data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/data) allows you to edit each pixel's rgb value directly.

```js
var can = document.getElementById('can');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
var imgData = ctx.createImageData(100, 100);

for(var i = 0; i < 100*100*4; i+=4) {
  imgData.data[i+0] = 0; // red
  imgData.data[i+1] = ((i/4)%100)/100*255; // green
  imgData.data[i+2] = Math.floor((i/4)/100)/100*255; // blue
  imgData.data[i+3] = 255; // alpha
}
ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas width="100" height="100" id="can"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks! Getting close now... I checked the ImageData constructor which accepts r,g,b,a (4 values) for each pixel... Are there any options for it to accept a plain rgb array (3 values) without the 'a' component? Thanks